# Borland Builder 5 c++ Strings can't index at 0

Tags: c++, string, c++builder, c++builder-5

I am trying to do a simple string access at 0, and for some reason I get an out of bounds error in Borland Builder 5 C++.

Has anyone found a way around this? Is there a special type of string that the Borland Compiler uses?

Comment: Yes. They're 1-based, because C++Builder and Delphi share common types. (The VCL in C++Builder is written in and compiled by Delphi's compiler.) So use 1-based indexing, or convert them to a C++ compatible string if you have to have 0-based indexing for some reason.

Comment: What's funny is that handling of index 0 is not equal throughout all of the AnsiString methods. For example, in BCB5, `SubString()` will return an empty string and not raise an error if you give it an index less than 1. But in BCB6 and later, indexes less than 1 are silently mapped to index 1 instead.

Comment: @Remy, that is strange. I posted a comment instead of an answer because I knew you'd see the question and could answer it better than I could; I seldom use Builder. :-)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Yes, It is a special String type used by Borland C++ Builder. 
Variables of this type are indexed from 1.

I know that it may be a bit confusing - I also couldn't believe it for a long time.